# Check YouTube URLs in bulk

Tags: video, youtube, status

We're looking for a way to check a LONG list of YouTube URLS for videos that are now private, have been deleted, or otherwise not available anymore. We can check the status, but the URL returns a 200 even if the video is no longer publicly available. For example these two:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/kIboBC_-FRE

https://www.youtube.com/embed/kFenGaDfuI4

The first has been made private and the second is still available. But they both return 200s.

Anybody know of a way to check the availability of YouTube videos in bulk?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this list an actual Youtube playlist?

Comment: No. Just a list of URLs of embedded videos on various sites we host. We need to be able to cleanup old dead embedded videos.

Answer (score 4):

> The first has been made private:
> https://www.youtube.com/embed/kIboBC_-FRE
>
> The second is still available:
> https://www.youtube.com/embed/kFenGaDfuI4
>
> They both return 200's (OK status). How to check the availability of YouTube videos
> in bulk... for videos that are now **private**, have been **deleted**, or
> otherwise **not available** anymore?

You could also try checking video status via Youtube's [OEmbed method](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2009/10/oembed-support_9.html):

To solve your problem, just do an HTTP request using the URL format shown below:

> https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=YOUR_FULL_YOUTUBE_PATH_HERE

examples:

1. `https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIboBC_-FRE`.
   Because the above is **private** this returns text "`Unauthorized`".

2. `https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5mpcDWpYSA`.
   Because the above is **deleted**, this returns text "`Not Found`".

3. `https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFenGaDfuI4`.
   Because the above is **availabe** this returns some JSON text "`{...etc...`". That also gives you other details like thumbnail url, uploader's name and the video title, etc... if that's useful in some way.

JSON entries include: (can be fixed with `myString.replace("\/", "//");`)...

```
{
  "title":"Kinetic Road Machine",
  "thumbnail_url":"https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/kFenGaDfuI4\/hqdefault.jpg",
  "author_url":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/user\/KineticbyKurt",
  "author_name":"Kinetic by Kurt"
  .... etc
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do it would be using [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) app.

If if you run it on a private video as:

```
$ youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/embed/kIboBC_-FRE
[youtube] kIboBC_-FRE: Downloading webpage
[youtube] kIboBC_-FRE: Downloading embed webpage
[youtube] kIboBC_-FRE: Refetching age-gated info webpage
WARNING: Unable to extract video title
WARNING: unable to extract description; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
ERROR: Content Warning
If the owner of this video has granted you access, please sign in.
       This video is private.
```

It will return `1` you can check it with `echo $?`.

Non private video will return 0 (and print a list of available formats).

So just write a simple script where you read your URLs line by line and check if `youtube-dl -F <url>` returned 0. Simple stuff.

Have fun.